# How to implement a regression with non-independent observations in the DV?

Tags: regression, modeling, independence, assumptions

I have a design where a number of object pairs were rated for association strength. These pairwise association ratings along 5 criteria of interest are expected to be used as IVs in a regression.

These pairs include a target object being paired with one of 4 accompanying objects to create the different types of association of interest. Therefore, I have 4 relation types. The DV represents the frequency each of these relation types is chosen over the others, in many 2AFC trials where 2 of the 4 possible accompanying objects are presented with the target object.

Thus, the problem with independence of the observations. When I quantify the frequency of choosing A over B, C and D, this is not independent of the frequency of choosing B over A, C or D. An easy fix would be to quantify the frequency of choosing A over B, A over C and A over D independently but I think I am losing important variance this way and I really want to avoid it.

One assumption is that the 5 IVs of interest might be significant predictors for some but not all of the 4 relation types. Therefore, I want to run a regression which predicts the DV (frequency of choice A, B, C and D) based on the 5 IVs.

**Question 1**: 
   My prefered way of quantifying the DV violates the assumption of independent observations, making the use of a multiple linear regression difficult. Would there be a different approach I can use that is not so sensitive to the independence of observations? E.g. SEM, PCA or some other type of regression (e.g. multi-model regression)?

**Question 2**: 
   What would be the effect of this violation of independence of measures? If I do use a multiple linear regression despite that, would it work against me and lead to a conservative fit of my model, potentially hiding significant effects, or would it overfit the data showing an inflated R square?

**Addendum**
   Let's assume that A is chosen 70% of the time. The other 30% will be spread over B, C and D. Let's assume B is chosen 60% of time, the rest will be spread between A, C and D, and so on. Is there any case where I could theoretically say that I am not so concerned about this "minor" independence violation and still do a multiple linear regression on these, rather than split the variance in the way described in my 3rd paragraph above, where the accompanying variance loss would be detrimental to my aim?